# DOM returned value for childNode

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="drum">
 <li>A<span>span text A</span></li>
 <li>S<span>span text S</span></li>
 <li>D<span>span text D</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JS:

```
let ul = document.querySelectorAll('.drum li');
let ulLen = ul.length;
let arr = [];  
for(var i=0; i<ulLen; i++) {
 if(ul[i].childNodes[0] === '\"S\"') {
  console.log('why is this not returning?');
 }
}
```

I am trying to match the `childnode` value of `S.` When I console.log the `ul[i].childNodes[0]` I can see the return value to be "S" but I am just not understanding why the `if` condition is not being satisfied. What am I missing? I have also tried the `firstChild` property, but still can't satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a Node to a string, you have to get the text content of the node then do the comparison. Also, remove the double quotes.

```js
let ul = document.querySelectorAll('.drum li');
let ulLen = ul.length;
let arr = [];  
for(var i=0; i<ulLen; i++) {
 if(ul[i].childNodes[0].textContent === 'S') {
  console.log('why is this not returning?');
 }
}
```

```html
<ul class="drum">
 <li>A<span>span text A</span></li>
 <li>S<span>span text S</span></li>
 <li>D<span>span text D</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow this is awesome! And completely new to me. How can I know in the future if I am targeting a `node` or a `property/value` in DOM. Any recommend reading? Thanks again!

Comment: Well you can use `typeof`, although `typeof ul[i].childNodes[0]` will give you `object` but I guess you'll know its not a string. There is also `instanceof`, `ul[i].childNodes[0] instanceof Node` will evaluate as true. And then there are the docs like [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)